# Paypal Return Value Question

Tags: php, paypal

How can I manipulate the code so that the return value is sent to my thank you page (www.website.com/thankyou.php) instead of the root homepage, while keeping everything else intact? The code to my paypal return value is listed below.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" 
    value="<?=$cfg->wwwroot."registration-confirmed-".base64_encode(serialize(array($user->id, 1)))?>">
```

Comment: If this is PHP code, then you should have the "php" tag. The "value" tag is kind of odd. I'm not sure it adds any value to say that you are dealing with values. Most code does. Tagging the question more accurately will help the relevant experts find this question. People tend to look at questions with their favorite tags more closely.

Comment: I've edited the question as well as added the tag 'php'.  Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PDT (Payment Data Transfer) for this purpose.

[This reference](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer) should be helpful. There are instructions on activating PDT at the bottom of the page.

Once you've setup PDT, simply change your input's name from 'return' to 'custom'.

In your code, which reads PDT data (thankyou.php), issue a redirect to 'custom' value that you'll get from Paypal PDT data. Example PHP script for PDT [is here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/pdt-codesamples-pop-outside#php).